# Matplotlib plot of 2D data

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis, axis, figure

I have data of shape (1125, 2058) that I want to make a 2D plot of. The x-axis corresponds to wavelengths and I have a numpy array called 'lam_gal' for it and the y-axis corresponds to radii r. My center (r=0) is at y=596, from this I calculate my radii as:

```
y_vals = np.arange(1125)
radii =np.asarray(0.2 * (596-y_vals))
```

The code for my plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=fig_dim)

# Create a 2D plot of the galaxy spectrum using imshow
im=ax.imshow(data_gal, cmap='binary', extent=(lam_gal[0], lam_gal[-1], radii[0], radii[-1]))

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('Wavelength')
ax.set_xlim(4900, 5450)
ax.set_ylabel('r')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

With the  result:
[image]

There are two problems with the y-axis here, first how can i set my y-axis labels to be all positive since a negative radius is unphysical and second the 0-tick does not align with the central line (dark line), but I am pretty sure that for y=596 this is the central line.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by:`radii =np.asarray(0.2 * ((1125-596)-y_vals))`
and defining a custom tick formatter function: `def y_tick_formatter(value, _): return f'{abs(value):.0f}'`
and using it in the plot:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(y_tick_formatter))
```